# setting up 3 node hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I want to setup a cluster of 3 nodes in my office innovation lab. All the 3 machines are having windows 7 installed. so I thought of creating a cluster using Ubuntu installed on all the 3 machines. so far I have followed below steps.

1. Installed VM ware on all the 3 machines
2. Installed Ubuntu on the 3 machines.
3. installed java 1.8 on all the machines

Please guide me what all steps do I need to follow to setup the cluster?
I have seen few videos where in they have created some local repository and did some setup for httpd also

thank
Brijesh

Comment: [Here](http://hadoop4admins.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_3.html) you can find a very good explanation and installation of Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

first you install hadoop version  this command

**rpm  -ivh hadoop**

then goes hadoop directory

**cd /etc/hadoop**

and open here hdfs-site.xml file and core-site.xml and edit property

**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkTIy.png**

**[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uf89i.png**

that's called is datanode . try  if possible so on..

Comment: where to put the details for 2 data node..?

Comment: use other system and become namenode which manage datanode matadata